# How to deserialize json using objectMapper which has variable key

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I have a json file like this. I want to convert this to object of my custom class that has the ID,SYMBOL,COUNT,SYMBOLINDEX as member variable, I cannot directly do it with objectMapper since the keys are varibale "0", "1", "434" they will be integers but are variable. They might also not be in incremental manner for example it can be like "323" then next can be like "5" so how can i convert this to object using objectMapper. Any code suggestions would be highly appreciated

````
        "0": {
            "symbol": "B",
            "count": 2,
            "symbolIndex": [0, 0]
        },
        "1": {
            "symbol": "B",
            "count": 2,
            "symbolIndex": [0, 0]
        },
        "2": {
            "symbol": "B",
            "count": 2,
            "symbolIndex": [0, 0]
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: Well, you can always use the generic parsing methods which will basically spit out a hierarchy of maps (objects) and lists (arrays). Off the top of my head I'd say you should also be able to pass a type reference to tell jackson to parse the json to `Map<String, YourCustomClass>` (also see [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map)). If everything else fails you could also provide your own deserializer for the first level but I doubt that's really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
    Map convertValue;
    try {
        convertValue = map.readValue(json, Map.class);
        System.out.println(convertValue.values());
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

You will get result like:
[{symbol=B, count=2, symbolIndex=[0, 0]}, {symbol=B, count=2, symbolIndex=[0, 0]}, {symbol=B, count=2, symbolIndex=[0, 0]}]